# Reading DPI data from an Image using matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I read the X and Y DPI information from an image using Matlab?
imfinfo doesnt seems to supply this information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all images have resolution information. It contained in EXIF (Exchangeable Image File Format) tags. Only JPEG and TIFF files may contain EXIF, it usually supplied by digital camera or scanner. If it's there you can get it from IMFINFO output.

```
info = imfinfo(filename);
xres = info.XResolution;
yres = info.YResolution;
resunit = info.ResolutionUnit;
```

You can always check if those fields exist:

```
if isfield(info,'XResolution')
    ...
end
```

**UPDATE**:

As for BMP files, they have `HorzResolution` and `VertResolution` properties that represent resolution in **pixels per meter** according to [BMP format standard](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm). You can multiply those values by 0.0254 to get DPI (approximately).

Comment: I have a simple BMP file. using ifran I can see the DPI and using imfinfo I can't access this information

Comment: As documentatino for imfinfo states EXIF tags are supported for JPEG and TIFF only. Do you have `HorzResolution` and `VertResolution` fields in imfinfo output?

Comment: Yes I do. but how do I extract the resolution(DPI) from these values?

Comment: These **ARE** the resolutions in X- and Y-directions. Simply use `info = imfinfo(filename)` and than use `info.HorzResolution` and `info.VertResolution`

Comment: Those values are pixels per meter (BMP standard). To get DPI multiply it by 0.0254 (with certain precision, of course).

Answer (score 0):

For which image type?
`imfinfo()` actually can return values for DPI provided as `XResolution` and `YResolution`, but I don't know for which image-types.